# Does Yahoo's PlaceFinder API always return 0 or 1 result for a reverse (lat/lng) lookup?

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, yahoo-api

I'm familiar with the geonames API, whose findNearbyPlaceName resource takes an optional radius parameter and can return multiple places for a given lat/lng pair.

When doing a similar lookup in YDN PlaceFinder, using the R gflag to do a reverse lookup from a lat/lng, will there ever be more than 1 result returned? I have not found any instances yet, and from what I can tell, the PlaceFinder API doesn't allow for radius (though you can request offset from street).

Comment: I would assume it can return multiple.  The documentation does not specify, which makes me think that it can.  (Everything else can return more than 1 location, so I would think they would specify if that could not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the PlaceFinder service will only return a single location. (In the case of an error or location not found, you would get 0 results.) It's designed to go between a place description and location (e.g., street address to lat/long).

I'm not sure what your needs are, but you could also check out the Yahoo GeoPlanet API which provides more hierarchical data around the point of interest. PlaceFinder and GeoPlanet can be used together in this way.

Here are a couple of hack projects that help demonstrate each of these APIs:

- [Placefinder Explorer](http://isithackday.com/hacks/geo/placefinder/)
- [GeoPlanet Explorer](http://isithackday.com/geoplanet-explorer/)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was beginning to assume. We do use PF in conjunction with GP. Wish this was in the API documentation though, since there is a very similar Geonames resource findNearbyPlaceName that returns multiple results based on a radius (in kilometers) parameter.